# magento api response time

Tags: magento

What is your "average" Magento Core API response time?

I'm getting ~1.5seconds just to make a SOAP call and return a number (I already have a soap object and session id). Not sure if terrible server or magento.

Any tips on improving Magento API response time? Thanks.

Comment: Is wsdl caching enabled in your client? Is Web Services Configuration cache enabled on your magento instance?

Comment: Not that I know of, I will take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think knowing the "average" response times other users have with *their* individual Magento SOAP API calls will be of much help here.

As long as these other users are not requesting the very same server, from at least the same subnet *your* client is in, this would result in comparing apples and oranges.

I can confirm, that server-side execution time of some Magento SOAP API methods *can* be quite time consuming. Especially, if the SOAP API method being used causes many database *writes* of data which is modelled the EAV way and having *huge* databases.

But as you seem to be talking about a method just *reading* a value via SOAP (you didn't mention which API method you use exactly), I doubt it's the API methods code being slow.

I'd strongly recommend, to first identify the location of your requests actual bottleneck to be

- client-side
- transmission
- server-side

before even starting trying to optimize API methods.

The bottleneck *can* be the result of a wrong cache/system configuration, on one or even both sides (client/server).

Or having a client/server which permanently runs under heavy load.

Or having long round trip times (RTT) for whatever reasons (just imagine having a `ping` of 700ms).

Or it could be the DNS lookups on client-side slowing things down.

Or it could even be the browser just slowly rendering the output of the request, because the output uses a complex layout and download hundreds of other files (hehe, had that once, hated it^^).

I'd probably first have a quick `ping` to the server (in parallel to your request) to see the RTT and to know whether I can exclude transmission as the bottleneck.

If you're on Firefox, you could also directly have a look at Firebugs Net panel instead. Check the requests timeline to see whether the bottleneck is client-side, dns/transmission or server-side.

Comment: For one, it was the server I was using, tested with another server, getting 0.5 sec responses. Will also def look over other suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Jurgen, do you have any tips on how to go about profiling API calls, once client-side and transmission bottlenecks are ruled out?  I actually posted a question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479722/easy-way-to-profile-magento-api-calls