# Easy way to profile Magento API calls

Tags: magento

Is there an easy way to profile Magento API calls?  Did a few searches and the best result I came up with was [this one](http://www.coolryan.com/magento/2012/04/06/varien-profiler-for-magento/) where the guy mentions that there isn't any functionality for this.

I guess it shouldn't be too hard to maybe pop a quick log statement inside Varien/Profiler.php, but I had assumed this might be a little more out-of-the-box-ish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, afaik there's no OOB/built-in way to profile Magento API calls.

Most API methods use standard models in the end, which *do* have `Varien_Profiler` calls embedded, so you still can get some profiling data. See `Mage_Core_Block_Profiler::_toHtml()` on how to.

*But*, there are no `Varien_Profiler` calls embedded in the API servers and adapters (SOAP, etc.) afaik, so you wouldn't get any profiling data of these areas (at least not without changing the code).

#### PHP Profiler

I'd rather recommend to install a PHP profiler instead of using `Varien_Profiler`.

A PHP profiler usually automatically covers *all* the PHP code being executed. It works for *any* PHP script and you dont' need to change anything in your PHP scripts to make it work.

[Xdebug's Profiler](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) in combination with some analyzing/visualization frontend like [webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/) or [KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/show.cgi) for example, would give you detailed profiling data, even of Magento API calls.

Comment: Thanks @Jurgen.  I ended up just implementing a quick feature to pull the varien proile data and log to a log file for API calls.